# Cannot find Ruby or Rails in my computer after installing Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, deployment, heroku

I just started to learn Rails from railstutorial.org. After installing Rails I cerated an app, set up git, installed Heroku gem, and uploaded SSH key to heroku.

After that, I turned off my computer and a few hours later I came back to continue with the next steps. First I ran `heroku create --stack cedar`.

Then,

`git push heroku master` I get the following error message:

`[~ (master)]$ git push heroku master
fatal: 'heroku' does not appear to be a git repository
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly`

Same thing is happening for commands like `rails` `heroku` `gem` etc.

Also, I cannot find neither Ruby or Rails in my system. When I ran `ruby -v` I get

`The program 'ruby' can be found in the following packages:
 * ruby1.8
 * ruby1.9.1
Try: sudo apt-get install <selected package>`

Is this happening because I am running Ruby 1.9.3p125? Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just type

```
rvm gemset list
```

rvm use 1.9.3@(you_gemset) --default

**EDIT**: i've looked this tutorial, and there he's created gemset: **rails3tutorial2ndEd**
then just type: `rvm use 1.9.3@rails3tutorial2ndEd --default`

Answer (score 0):

You probably haven't set ruby 1.9.3 as your default ruby with rvm. You can do this by typing in the command line:

```
rvm use 1.9.3 --default
```

This should solve your problem.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I did that earlier. Didn't set a default gemset.